# table of contents in second page, title in the first

Tags: table-of-contents, titles

I am trying to write title in first page, and after table of contents:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


    \title{My Title}
    \author{My Name}

    \newpage


    \tableofcontents


    \section{Installation}
    aaaaaaaaaaaa
    \subsection{Getting started}
    \subsection{Jamaican rice rat}
    \subsection{White-footed rabbit-rat}

    \section{Butterflies}
    \subsection{Nymphalidae}
    \subsection{Lycaenidae}
    \subsection{Uraniidae}



\end{document}
```

but it displays only one page with table of contents

Comment: What document class are you using? If you are using `book`, just add `\maketitle` _before_ `\tableofcontents`.

Comment: I'm using `\documentclass{article}`

Comment: How do you want the title page to look like?

Comment: @JouleV After I added `\maketitle` it works, please post as answer

Comment: I added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to add `\maketitle` *before* `\newpage`. This command will generate the title.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \title{My Title}
    \author{My Name}
    \maketitle
    \newpage
    \tableofcontents
    \section{Installation}
    aaaaaaaaaaaa
    \subsection{Getting started}
    \subsection{Jamaican rice rat}
    \subsection{White-footed rabbit-rat}
    \section{Butterflies}
    \subsection{Nymphalidae}
    \subsection{Lycaenidae}
    \subsection{Uraniidae}
\end{document}
```

[image][image]

However, IMHO you should *not* use `\newpage` in this case. `article` already provides `titlepage` option.

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{article}
\begin{document}
    \title{My Title}
    \author{My Name}
    \maketitle
    \tableofcontents
    \section{Installation}
    aaaaaaaaaaaa
    \subsection{Getting started}
    \subsection{Jamaican rice rat}
    \subsection{White-footed rabbit-rat}
    \section{Butterflies}
    \subsection{Nymphalidae}
    \subsection{Lycaenidae}
    \subsection{Uraniidae}
\end{document}
```

and the title page is much nicer

[image]

For more customization, you can use `titlepage` environment.